# Download and store GRIB2 files in Azure

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine

Currently, on my Linux Docker container, I have a bash script that is able to download many many GRIB2 weather forecast files from a specific URL with a login by cookie.
Once those files are downloaded, I use an executable from the ECCODES library that I installed in that same Docker container to filter out the unneeded data in order to reduce the files size.

My company has access to the Azure platform and I would like to download and filter those GRIB2 files directly in the Azure platform so I don't have to run manually the script and to always download files and then upload them to an Azure storage.

However, I have never worked with Azure before so what I would like to know is :

would it be possible to run this script in maybe an Azure VM that would download and store directly the filtered GRIB2 files in an Azure storage (Blob storage seems to be the best option based on what I've read so far) ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is that you want to how to download file from Azure blob and upload file to Azure blob? If so, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-vm-windows-access-storage

Comment: Thanks @JimXu, I've been working my way through Azure documentation, I've written a bash script that creates the blob storage container and upload files if they don't exist.
I'm about to start C++ implementation to download those files in my application.

Comment: Since your issue has been resolved, could you please post your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=your_azure_storage_account
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY=your_azure_storage_access_key

# Retrieving current date to upload only new files
date=`date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ`

az login -u xxx@yyy.com -p password --output none

containerName=your_container_name

containerExists=`az storage container exists --account-name $AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT --account-key $AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY --name $containerName --output tsv`
if [[ $containerExists == "False" ]]; then
    az storage container create --name $containerName # Create a container
fi

# Upload GRIB2 files to container
fileExists=`az storage blob exists --account-name $AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT --account-key $AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY --container-name $containerName --name "gfs.0p25.2019061300.f006.grib2" --output tsv`
if [[ $fileExists == "False" ]]; then
    az storage blob upload --container-name $containerName --file ../Resources/Weather/Historical_Data/gfs.0p25.2019061300.f006.grib2 --name gfs.0p25.2019061300.f006.grib2
fi
```